# Why is my nginx config allowing access to app.domain.com?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a subdomain called app pointed to my host via the DNS but I don't want to use it for my current website that uses the subdomain xyz. If I go to https://app.domain.com I get the "Your connection is not private" error. This is good that the browser shows this but I don't want anyone to even access this subdomain at the moment. I would prefer to redirect them to https://xyz.domain.com in which I have a valid SSL. Please see my config below and help me figure out what i'm missing. Thanks in advance.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name xyz.domain.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://xyz.domain.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    # For https
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name xyz.domain.com;

    if ($http_host = app.domain.com) {
        rewrite ^ https://xyz.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.domain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users to not get the security warning, you'll need to set up a secondary server configuration and configure `certbot` to obtain a certificate for `app.domain.com`:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    server_name app.domain.com;

    rewrite ^ https://xyz.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.domain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but is there a way to just redirect the user immediately?

Comment: I get the following error by doing this: nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:443 in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf:31

Comment: I don't like having to add another cert for the subdomain but i guess that's how it works. Tried running `certbot certonly 
    ...
    -d *.domain.com`
for a wildcard but that didn't work.

Comment: Yup, the browser can't really do the redirect without validating the cert first. LE wildcards take a little bit of doing but not too much, I trust you worked out the earlier issue with duplicate listen options.